# Lua shutdown/End of the program execution callback

Tags: c, lua, luabind

I am writing a module for Lua. On closing the lua interpreter it must run clean up routines even if user forgets to call shutdown routine implicitly.

The module is mostly written in C.

What callback in Lua C Api should I use to detect end of program execution? The only idea I have come with is using __gc metamethod on table representing my module. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a C module, the simple thing to do is to create a full `userdata` with a `metatable` with a `__gc` metamethod. Store it in a field in the module's environment so it isn't collected by the GC until the module is unloaded.

According to [the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.10.1), only `userdata` get their `__gc` metamethod called by the collector, so you can't use a table to hold the module's finalizer.

For a module written in pure Lua that needs a finalizer, you still need to have a `userdata` to hold it up. The unsupported and undocumented but widely known function [`newproxy()`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/HiddenFeatures) can be used to create an otherwise empty `userdata` with a metatable to use for this purpose. Call it as `newproxy(true)` to get one with a metatable, and use `getmetatable()` to retrieve the metatable so you can add the `__gc` metamethod to it.

Comment: Seems to be working fine (inside lua module - close is a shutdown routine)

Comment: local shutdownproxy = newproxy(true)  -- create proxy object with new metatable
assert(type(shutdownproxy) == 'userdata')
getmetatable(shutdownproxy).__gc = function() print "GC"; ivrworx.close(); print "GC1"; end